# Disable Controls in Word Application

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, ms-word, office-interop

I have downloaded a component (Edraw Viewer Component) for word documents viewing, customization, etc...
I could not post the image since I need 10 reputation.
Please find the question on MSDN forum on the [following link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b0f8ba0-979f-481d-b3fc-8270e33130dc/disabling-word-functionalities?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues).

(In case the text written on image is not visible, Please find it below)
***TEXT:***
After selecting a word document, it seems that the EDRAW viewer control is changing the parent window of the word application and set it to an MDI contained form that opens within the main menu (check image; you could see that the MS-Word app is embedded within the windows form.)

What is really confusing, is how could they access the Copy, cut and paste buttons and disable them. 
Also note that the latter buttons were disabled at the level of the document and not the entire application. (This means whenever I open another instance of MS-Word outside the menu, Copy-Cut and paste are enabled).
The software is not using CustomUI to customize the ribbon, nor VBA scripts, plus, the Word Object Model does not expose any property or method related to these buttons.
Please note that I have also tried using windows automation, accessed the word application and all of its controls (Tab, Buttons...), but the Control IDs were never accessible. 
Please Find a code snippet:

```
     Private _clientAppRootInstance As AutomationElement = Nothing
       Me._clientAppRootInstance = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Document1 - Microsoft Word"))
    For Each inst as AutomationElement In Me._clientAppRootInstance.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, _
                    New OrCondition( _
                    New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button), _
                    New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Custom) _
                    ))
  If CType(inst.Current, AutomationElement.AutomationElementInformation).Name = "Copy" Then
                        If inst.Current.AutomationId <> "" Then
                            PstBtnID = inst.Current.AutomationId
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
```

At this level, please note that all inst.Current.AutomationID (which represent the ControlID, that I shall allow me accessing control handle and using windows API functions to manipulate its behavior) is always empty.

I tried this same example on windows calculator (calc.exe) and it worked like dream ( I could access each button through its controlID)

Your Help is much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried using Accessibility API?

Comment: **Re-post** of [Disabling Word Functionalities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471445/disabling-word-functionalities)

Comment: I know, but I thought nobody was answering because the question was rated -2 by somebody who did not manage to see the text written on the picture.

Comment: (Eugene) : I tried Accessibility API, 
However, the related buttons are Read Only. I took the project found on the link below, managed to access all the ribbon toolbars and controls, however, all methods are getter and not setters. (Read Only Properties).
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38906/UI-Automation-Using-Microsoft-Active-Accessibility